What options are available to handle the dynamic routes in Sitecore and Next.js?
What options are available to handle the dynamic pages in Sitecore and Next.js? Let's say we have created a page called "devpage" and we have the dynamic routes like this devpage/{dynamic URL part}.
Generally, Sitecore will display a 404 page when navigating to devpage/user1 URL. Is there a way to handle it from Sitecore side?
What are the ways to completely create a new page only from the Next.js side without creating a page in the Content Editor? So, we can handle the dynamic routes in the Next.js way. We may have to modify the routing mechanism in the SXA Starter template in Next.js.

sounds like Wildcards in Sitecore would do the work for you https://developers.sitecore.com/learn/accelerate/xm-cloud/implementation/information-architecture/wildcard-pages

Check out Wildcard pages defined in the XM Cloud accelerate documentation. See https://developers.sitecore.com/learn/accelerate/xm-cloud/implementation/information-architecture/wildcard-pages

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
